# unserialize is not working when i m using pgsql

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-5

here is my controller

```
public function getProfile()
 {
$orders = Auth::user()->orders;
$orders->transform(function($orders,$key){
$orders->cart = unserialize($orders->cart);
return $orders;
 });
return view('user.profile',['orders'=>$orders]);
}
```

here is my DB column cart value

```
 "O:8:"App\Cart":3:{s:5:"items";a:1:{i:1;a:3:
{s:3:"qty";i:1;s:5:"price";i:20;s:4:"item";O:11:"App\Product":24:
{s:5:"table";s:8:"products";s:11:""
```

i want to fetch particular value from cart for eg :- price";i:20 or "item";O:11:"

here is my view

```
@foreach($orders as $order)
                    @foreach($order->cart->items as $item)
                        <span class="badge">₹{{ $item['price'] }}</span>
                        {{ $item['item']['title'] }} | {{ $item['qty'] }} 
        <strong>Total Price: ₹{{ $order->cart->totalPrice }}</strong>
    @endforeach
```

its throw error like when using unserialize() like this unserialize(): Error at offset 138 of 142 bytes
if i use serialize then its throw error in my profile view eg(Trying to get property of non-object)

Comment: That doesn't look like a correctly serialized value. Make sure your DB column was big enough to fit all of it in because that looks truncated.

Comment: have already stored value in column

Comment: That is not a valid serialized value.

Comment: @apokryfos not getting properly please give some  demo or link where i can understand

Comment: If you go to http://blog.tanist.co.uk/files/unserialize/ and put that string in there it will tell you: *Not a valid input* .

Comment: @apokryfos   its working on mysql but not in pgsql

Comment: @apokryfos    its work on mysql but not work in pgsql

Comment: What's your column definition in mysql and in pgsql and also what's the collation. Make sure you're storing it in binary fields  because serialised strings are binary strings.

Comment: @apokryfos   mysql store "text" data type and pgsql store value "text" datatype